# Strange characters preceding string in C

Tags: c

My processes array is filled with the following strings:

```
#define MAX_LINES 100
#define MAX_LEN 100

char processes[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN];
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

0 3 * * *      daily-backup
15 4 * * sun   weekly-backup
0 10 22 7 mon  deep-thought
59 16 16 8 *   submit-project
0 2 1 * *      send-monthly-newsletter
```

I'm using the following code to clean it up:

```
    char times[clean_line][100];
    
    for (int z=0;z<clean_line;z++) {
        int x = 0;
        int space_counter = 0;
        while ( (processes[z][x] != '\0') && (space_counter < 5) ) {
            if (processes[z][x] == ' ') {
                strcat(times[z], "/");
                space_counter++;
                x++;
            }
            else {
                strncat(times[z], &processes[z][x], 1);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

That code produces this:

```
0/3/*/*/*/
15/4/*/*/sun/
0/10/22/7/mon/
����59/16/16/8/*/
K��U0/2/1/*/*/
```

Those first 3 lines look fine, but the last 2 have bad characters at the start.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least this issue:

`strcat(times[z], "/");` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `times[z]` is not certainly a *string*, as required.

Initialize/assign `times[]` to start them off as *strings* by at least zeroing the first element: `times[i][0]`.

```
// char times[clean_line][100];
char times[clean_line][100] = { 0 };  // Fill all with zeros.

// or
char times[clean_line][100];
for (int z=0;z<clean_line;z++) {
  times[z][0] = '\0';
}
```